# How to remove or solve Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I m using two theme...one is for desktop and one is for mobile...
In both file one class name is same in his lib
the class name is mobile_detect ...so when i m using both theme i found one 
error....Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Mobile_Detect in `E:\xampp\htdocs\gala_theme_magento-9\lib\em\Mobile_Detect.php on line 34`...

SO i need to know that without renaming class name how can i resolved this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your Theme should imho not add something to the lib folder... This should be done by a custom extension that must (and can) only be installed once and can be disabled independently from the theme.

To resolve your issue, find the place where the second file (that tries to define the class a second time) is included and remove this. Again, not the "right" way though.

Comment: I find that and also rename...but when its goes on mobile..than both theme called....but error is resolved.....